# Access the child (Button) of a prefab and add function OnClick to it. Unity

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, button, onclick, game-development

I have a prefab which contains some buttons and I want to get the buttons and add specific onClick functions to them via script. I cant find the right way to get the buttons.
What I am trying is:

```
    tempGo = Instantiate(prefabs[0]);

    tempGo.transform.SetParent(transform, false);

    tempGo.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
    tempGo.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

    Transform t = tempGo.GetComponentInChildren<Transform>().Find("AddGoals");
```

**"AddGoals" Is my Buttons(Tag name)**

So after this point how can I code it to add a specific function when the button gets clicked?

Any help would be appreciated  thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get button component and add listener to it. Listener will call the function when that button is clicked. TaskOnClick is an example function that will be called when the button is clicked.

```
t.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);


void TaskOnClick()
{
    Debug.Log("You have clicked the button!");
}
```

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UiManager.Start () (at Assets/scripts/UiManager.cs:26)
Do you think my previous code is the mistake? Or the Find("AddGoals") didnt work?

Comment: Make sure you assigned the tag("AddGoals") to your button.

Comment: Hi! Please add an explanation to the solution as code only answers are generally discouraged on SO. Thanks! --From Review.

Answer (score 1):

Using .Find(""), you are looking for a gameobject with that *name*, not its tag. What you can do is after instantiating the object, use GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("AddGoals"). This will return an array of all of the objects with that tag. Then with Linq you can do something like:

```
var items = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("AddGoals"); //This gives gameobject array
var itemTansforms = items.Select(x=>x.transfrom).ToList(); //gives you a list of the object tansforms
```

As for adding an event, you would need to grab the button component of the object and then add the onclick event.

```
items.ForEach(x=>x.GetComponent<Button>().AddListener(delegate {Debug.Log($"{x.name} has been clicked")}));
```

You would have to make sure it is actually a button, or the code will fail. This of course can be modified and is just an example. I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey the first Line of code gives me the following error: The name "FindGameObjectsWithTag" does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Put "GameObject" in front of it.

Comment: That is not very descriptive on the error you are having. The point of these answers is not to write the code for you, but to give you ideas on how to write the code. I am not sitting in front of unity and am giving you a vague idea about how to look at the problem you are having. Try this out, read the docs, then debug your problem.